# change date format in django

Tags: python, django

I'me trying to use [this eventCalendar](http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html) in Django, which saves and shows dates in this format:

```
2012-02-27T13:15:00.000+10:00
```

but when I save events in the database, they're saved in this format:

```
Mon Feb 27 2012 13:15:00 GMT+0330 (Iraq Standard Time)
```

so events from the database won't appear on the calendar because of this format. How can I convert this format?
I tried some thing like this:

```
datetime.strptime(mydatetime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000")
```

but I'm repeatedly getting errors like this:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'
```

Edit:date is in string format

Answer (score 5):

`strptime` is used to parse a string into a datetime object. The format string indicates how to parse the string, *not* the format you want the datetime to take when later printed as a string. So first off you need to make the format string match the date format of the input string.

Once you've gotten a datetime from `strptime`, you can then use `strftime` with your current format string to get it into the display you want.

That said, though, it appears you've got a problem with your imports. The error seems to indicate that you've done:

```
import datetime
datetime.strptime(...)
```

That's incorrect. `strptime` and `strftime` are methods off `datetime.datetime`, so you need to either modify your import like:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Or, modify your call to `strptime` like:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(...)
```

**UPDATE**

You're starting off with a string like `Mon Feb 27 2012 13:15:00 GMT+0330 (Iraq Standard Time)`. Python is pretty awesome, but it's not omniscient; if you want to convert this to a `datetime` you have to tell it *how*. That's the purpose of the format string you pass to `strptime`. You need to create a format string that represents your current string date and time as represented in the database (exercise left to reader). Think in reverse, along the lines of it you wanted to actually represent a `datetime` like that, how would you do it.

This will net you a `datetime`. From there, you can now format that `datetime` as a string with `strftime`, passing the actual format you want, this time.

So the process is:

1. Create a format string representing your *current* string from the database
2. Use that format string as an argument to `strptime` to get a `datetime`
3. Create a format string representing the format you want the date to be in (already done)
4. Use that format string as the argument to `strftime` to convert the `datetime` from step 2 to your desired string.

Comment: tnx,when fetching datetime from database and trying to format them to return them it as a json to show,I have this error:time data 'Mon Feb 27 2012 13:15:00 GMT+0330 (Iraq Standard Time)' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000'  ,that sounds like it cant change format!!

Comment: Again, the format string passed to `strptime` *must* tell it how to parse your current string-based date and time, *not* what you'd like it to be eventually.

Comment: sorry! but I really don't understand U :(

Comment: I'm so sorry!@Chris Pratt don't get furious.while U described well but I don't know why I have problem yet,this is an Embarrassing situation to me.