# change string containing datetime to another format of datetime

Tags: python, django

I have a string containing such data: `Mon Feb 27 2012 13:15:00 GMT+0330 (Iraq Standard Time)`
 ,I'm going to convert it to this format : `2012-02-27T13:15:00.000`
 , How can I do this?

**EDIT:** I finally did this:

```
strp_time = time.strptime(event.startTime, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
start = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',strp_time)
```

as U can see I've used this format : `%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z` for such string :`Mon Feb 27 2012 13:15:00 GMT+0330 (Iraq Standard Time)` , But it caused this error:

```
unconverted data remains: +0330 (Iraq Standard Time)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [change date format in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469943/change-date-format-in-django)

Comment: Just wanted to add a note I figure out after learning these methods a few weeks ago. It makes sense if the "P" in strptime() stands for "parse", and the "F" in strftime() stands for "format". 

So, we use the parse method to read through a string and turn it into a datetime object, while we use the format method to change a datetime object from one format to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry you're having a hard time understanding this, but creating a duplicate question is not the proper response. As I tried to explain in my answer to your first question, you singular problem here is that you're not passing the right format string to `strptime`.

`strptime` takes a *string* and returns a *datetime*. But, dates and times can be represented in a myriad of different ways. As a result, Python needs you to tell it how to break up the parts of that string. That is the purpose of the second parameter. You need to create a format string that *matches* the string you're trying to convert.

Comment: thank U so much and thank U for your attention.I updated my answer below,I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: this part is time zone : +0330 (Iraq Standard Time) ,ya? %Z is for time zone?

Comment: Try it, but I think %Z will only match the `+0330` part. Mostly likely you need to simply drop the `(Iraq Standard Time)` because I don't think `strptime` can parse that at all, and it's purely supplementary.

Comment: I dropped it in this way: start='Mon Feb 27 2012 13:15:00 GMT+0330 (Iraq Standard Time) ' then : start[34:63]=[] , but I get this error:'unicode' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Use a regex. `re.sub(r'\(.+?\)$', '', my_date_string)`

Comment: I tryed your regex and now I have this error:unconverted data remains: +0330 ,that sounds like it has not dropped the last space,but I don't know about regex syntax to correct this error.

Comment: then I tryed this format:'%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z ' (a space has been added to the end) , and I got this error: time data u'Wed Mar 07 2012 16:00:00 GMT+0330 ' does not match format '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z '

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the space preceding the parenthetical part. Just add a space after the `r'`.

Comment: headache!!! unconverted data remains: +0330,this is a part of time zone,I don't know why It cause this error!!

Answer (score 1):

Use strptime and strftime... http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Example...

```
from datetime import datetime
my_date = datetime.strptime(my_string, format)
my_new_string = my_date.strftime(format)
```

You can work out the format from the table of tokens on that link.

Comment: thanks!this page doesn't have example,I need a clear example.

Comment: Have added an example, but there is one on the page anyway.

Comment: The format for strptime is not correct as input string. Check these links for strptime(tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm) and strftime(tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm). Here you can find different formats for datetime object. For example: datetime.strptime('Mon Feb 27 2012 13:15:00', '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S')

Comment: Yes, all that information is provided on the link to the Python docs I provided, I guess you didn't want to read it.

Comment: but I read it and it really helped me to understand the subject

Comment: :-s ok, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the template tag [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date).

Comment: thanks buddy!I'm going do this in views.py then return it to template.